# Response statut 200 is OK but use jquery error function

Tags: jquery, json, web-services, http-headers, jersey

I have created a restfull web service that return a json result and the URL : myURL/annonces/contract/sepcifiedContract/1 return this result:

```
{"contractId":1,"labelContract":"INFO"}
```

and this is my script to get data:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/NoticeManagerServer/annonces/contract/sepcifiedContract/1",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: render,
        error: errorf,
        failure: failf      
    });         
});
function render(){
$("p").append("success function."); 
}
function failf(){
 $("p").append(" failure faunction."); 
}
function errorf(){
$("p").append("error function."); 
}
</script>
```

the html result is:

```
 error function.
```

what could be the problem?

Comment: The error function receives status arguments, why don't you display that and see the reason?

Comment: the status display "error".

Comment: the parameter error shows : Exception... "Access to restricted URI denied"  code: "1012" nsresult: "0x805303f4 (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)"  location: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js Line: 6"]

Comment: You're running into the AJAX same-origin policy. The URL has to be the same domain and port number as the page you're running the AJAX call on.

Comment: yes it's because I edited the url but now it shows: [Exception... "Failure"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: file:///D:/workspace/workspaceAndroid/FirstApp/assets/www/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js :: .send :: line 6"  data: no]

Comment: You can't do AJAX to `file:` URLs, only to servers.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a cross domain issue.
Try: `crossDomain: true`

Write this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/NoticeManagerServer/annonces/contract/sepcifiedContract/1",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: render,
    error: errorf,
    failure: failf      
});
```

Comment: this not resolve the problem, it still get me "error function"

Comment: That option doesn't disable the same-origin policy.